# Can I mark an internal function or variable as 'not documented' in l3doc?

Tags: cross-referencing, warnings, expl3, latex3, dtx

There are several internal variables I use that I do not see a need to document in the user-interface section, but I want to explain in the implementation.  I'd really like to remove the warnings about missing references.  Can I mark a variable or function as 'not documented' so it won't look for a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `l3doc`, the `macro` and `variable` environments takes an optional argument. This can be use to mark the code as

- `aux` Auxiliary and so not documented
- `EXP` Expandable
- `TF` Conditional with `T`, `F` and `TF` versions
- `int` Internal code which is documented but not for general use

Thus you want

```
\begin{variable}[aux]{<name(s)>}
```

Comment: `aux` is now deprecated. Looking at the source file I believe we should use `internal` instead.